# M-N relationship using Bookshelfjs

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

How do I query from a junction table to main table using bookshelfjs. 
here is my query

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  current_store_type_id,
  b.code as current_store_type_code,
  new_store_type_id, 
  c.code as new_store_type_code
FROM 
  store_upgrade a
JOIN lt_store_type b
ON a.current_store_type_id = b.id
JOIN lt_store_type c
ON a.new_store_type_id = c.id
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Please check my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/14a8f/1). For your information I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Bookshelf is meant to query your database in order to get nested objects. Here is the model you would need to query your database with Bookshelf.

```
var StoreType = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'lt_store_type'
});

var StoreUpgrade = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'store_upgrade',

    currentStore: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(StoreType, 'current_store_type_id');
    },
    newStore: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(StoreType, 'new_store_type_id');
    }
});
```

And the Bookshelf method to fetch the data

```
StoreUpgrade
    .forge()
    .fetchAll({ withRelated: ['currentStore', 'newStore'] })
    .then(data => {
        // Data retrieval
    })
    .catch(exc => {
        // Error management
    });
```

And this is the output you will get

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        currentStore: {
            id: 2,
            code: "KIWI"
        },
        newStore: {
            id: 3,
            code: "DURIAN"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        currentStore: {
            id: 1,
            code: "BANANA"
        },
        newStore: {
            id: 2,
            code: "KIWI"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: but this will produce three separate queries. How do I join them all in one liner

Comment: Bookshelf will produce an array of objects with nested store objects where knex will produce an array of flat rows containing columns from multiple tables in the same object. If you only want one query, you need knex and not Bookshelf. Bookshelf is not meant to do raw queries. It's an ORM meant to help you query your database and get objects with nested objects and context-based objects. What is your problem with multiple queries?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will start use knex then